# Why arrow functions don't work when using import/export

Tags: javascript, webpack

This code shows "show not defined."

```
import {a} from './dis.js';
show = () =>{
  console.log(a);
}
show();
```

But this works

```
import {a} from './dis.js';
const show = () =>{
    console.log(a);
}
show();
```

why is that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to the arrow functions. It's the nature of strict code. You can see an example when I work in the `strict` mode. What about `ES6` modules, they are automatically in `strict` mode.

```js
'use strict';

show = 4;
```

You are trying to assign a reference of an arrow function to a variable `show` which is not defined. Defined means that you have defined it with keyword `var`, `let` or `const` for variables.

In the first code part you haven't declare it with these keywords, it tries to find the variable and doesn't find anything defined with that name. So it throws error.

In the second code part you have defined a variable with name show and then assign to it a reference to an arrow function. So everything is OK.

Comment: Thank you so much...@Suren-srapyan

Comment: One more question.. if i do not use that import in the first code and display some string inside that console..it will work..why so?

Comment: If you have used `import` it means that your code under `strict` mode, if not it is a simple `js` file and there variables without keyword will be attached to the global object - `window.show`

Answer (score 2):

This is not due to arrow function. You are trying to assign a value to `show`, but have not defined that variable anywhere. Define it using `var`, `let` or `const`

While assigning without defining works in JS, it is not recommended, and not allowed in `strict` mode.